# How big will the joda time library be for an android application?

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, android-calendar

I need to implement a count down timer which countdowns from a specific date, after some research I understand that calendar class isnt the best at handling all this so I should use joda time. However I need this only **once** in my whole application, so I am concerned that it will be taking too much space in my app when I dont really need it.

So my question is, how much will the size of my application increase if I add joda time library to app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual size of the jar is much smaller than the zip file.  I just downloaded the zip file and the current jar that gets distributed (joda-time-2.3.jar) is only 568KB.

Comment: Ah, I already implemented my functionality using date/calendar class of java. Boy, hectic it was. Wish you would have answered this previously !!

Answer (score 1):

The ZIP with sources is about 4.1MB large.

this zip contains the jar which is about 568kB

Information taken from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/

Comment: so does that mean that my application's size will increase by 4.1 MB?

Comment: wow that is huge! My application is simple right now and is about 7.1 Mb, incorporating joda time will make it 11.1 MB that is too much, I have to figure out a way using calendar class now

Comment: please upvote and accept if this answer helped you and gave you the information you needed

Comment: Your answer was incorrect, the .jar file is only 568kB or so

Comment: well i posted where i got my information and thought it was correct. i believed inthat information, like you did in mine. sorry for that i updated my answer